# How to generate normal random variable vector which is spatially auto-correlated

Tags: autocorrelation, random-variable, spatial

I would like to generate normal random variable vector $\boldsymbol{x}_1$, which is correlated with $\boldsymbol{x}_2$. Also, I would like to introduce some kind of spatial auto-correlation into $\boldsymbol{x}_1$, and $\boldsymbol{x}_2$, respectively. How can we do this with standard statistical software like `R` or `MATLAB`? Any suggestion is very much appreciated.

Comment: In R, the function 'mvrnorm' (part of the MASS package) makes random generation for the multivariate normal distribution. Specific correlation structures can be obtained by modelling the variance-covariance matrix ('Sigma' argument).

Comment: If you can specify the covariance structure caused by the spatial autocorrelation in $x_1$ and $x_2$ as covariance matrices $\Sigma_{11}$ and $\Sigma_{22}$  and the covariance between $x_1$ and $x_2$ as $\Sigma_{12}$, and if you let $\boldsymbol{x}^T=(x_1^T,x_2^T)$, *then* $\boldsymbol{x}$ is multivariate normal with covariance matrix $\Sigma =\begin{bmatrix}\Sigma_{11} & \Sigma_{12} \\  \Sigma_{12}^T & \Sigma_{22} \end{bmatrix}$. So you can use any scheme for generating multivariate normals, though more efficient approaches may well come up if you get more specific.

Comment: I've described a [procedure here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/3865/1036) for one vector based on a given spatial weights matrix and a given level of autocorrelation.

Comment: Several `R` packages contain procedures for simulation (and conditional simulation) of Gaussian spatial processes, including `Spatial` and `geoRglm`. You need to supply a variogram model for the spatial autocorrelation (and both of these contain procedures to help estimate such a model from data).

Comment: also check out the `RandomFields` package, which has a *very* complete set of Gaussian simulation methods

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you can use some form of Cholesky transformation.

First you have a vector $x_1$ drawn from normal distribution and then you define spatial covariance matrix $\Sigma$, which has index for both spatial and temporal dimension. This matrix will be quite big depending on the form of spatial autocovariance.

I think that easiest example would be one which has some correlation for spatially adjacent points and this dependency declines geometrically. And autocorrelation structure could be represented by first-order process.

After that you make an Cholesky transformation $LL^T$ for the covariance matrix $\Sigma$.

If you premultiply vector $x_1$ by $L$ then you get vector $x_2$ and their correlation structure comes from the $\Sigma$ matrix.